# Line break after Inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating multiple checkbox inputs dynamically from a JSON:

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        data: codes,
        current: {}
    };

    render() {
        let data = this.state.data.map((code) => {
            return (
                <div className="form-part">
                    <h3>{code.title}</h3>
                    {(function () {
                        return code.options.map(option => <label><input type="checkbox" value={option.code}/>{option.label}</label>);
                    })()}
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <form>{data}</form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is that all generated inputs are in one line and I would like them to be underneath each other (for visual explanation see snippets below). I can't just add a `<br />` at the end because that wouldn't be valid JSX. Wrapping the entire thing and the `<br>` in a `<div></div>` would probably work but seems like a hack. How should this be done in React?

**Current output:**

```html
<div class="form-part">
  <h3>Numbers</h3><label><input type="checkbox" value="1">One</label><label><input type="checkbox" value="2">Two</label><label><input type="checkbox" value="3">Three</label>
</div>
```

**Desired output:**

```html
<div class="form-part">
  <h3>Numbers</h3>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="1">One</label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="2">Two</label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="3">Three</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line breaks are only supposed to be used when there's a real line break. In your case, since you are wrapping everything inside the `<label>` tag, please make the label as a block level display and give some margin bottom.

I would really suggest you to use the following CSS, instead of arbitrarily inserting `<br />` tags.

```css
.form-part label {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-part">
  <h3>Numbers</h3>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="1">One</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="2">Two</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="3">Three</label>
</div>
```

**React Code**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        title: "Hi",
        options: [
          { code: "Option 1", label: "Option 1" },
          { code: "Option 2", label: "Option 2" },
          { code: "Option 3", label: "Option 3" }
        ]
      }
    ],
    current: {}
  };

  render() {
    let data = this.state.data.map(code => {
      return (
        <div className="form-part">
          <h3>{code.title}</h3>
          {code.options.map(option => (
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" value={option.code} />
              {option.label}
            </label>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form>{data}</form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.form-part label {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

If you still require `<br />`s to be added, I have the code for you:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        title: "Hi",
        options: [
          { code: "Option 1", label: "Option 1" },
          { code: "Option 2", label: "Option 2" },
          { code: "Option 3", label: "Option 3" }
        ]
      }
    ],
    current: {}
  };

  render() {
    let data = this.state.data.map(code => {
      return (
        <div className="form-part">
          <h3>{code.title}</h3>
          {code.options.map(option => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <br />
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value={option.code} />
                {option.label}
              </label>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form>{data}</form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

> But remember, the above should not be used for layout purposes, which you are currently doing and it's semantically incorrect.

Comment: CSS is obviously the right way to go here and I feel kinda stupid now. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MiXT4PE I have also corrected your code in a better way after `<h3>{code.title}</h3>`, please consider this approach next time... 

Comment: @MiXT4PE I am a React JS mentor and a contributor. Please do ask me any questions you have... I am happy to help you out. 

Comment: Why are the `{ }` around `code.options.map()` necessary for `option` to be defined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192720/discussion-between-mixt4pe-and-praveen-kumar-purushothaman).

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in css with flex. You can put all the inputs in a div, give that div an id or class name, and then set `display` to `flex` and `flex-direction` to `column`.

```css
#inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-part">
  <h3>Numbers</h3>
  <div id='inputs'>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="1">One</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="2">Two</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="3">Three</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can learn all about flex here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Why do you need a Flex Box layout for such a small thing?

Comment: I find it gives great freedom over layout and is just as easy to use as margins. Any reason it shouldn't be used?

Comment: Browser Compatibility... 

Comment: It's compatible with every single modern browser including all phone ones according to caniuse. IE only has partial support but even microsoft doesn't want people to use IE anymore so I don't see much issue here personally.